# how should I store xml data in a java class

Tags: java, xml

I am just beginning to learn to read xml in java. My question is very basic. How do I store attributes and sub-elements of an xml element in a java class.

Thus if I have a simple xml file as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
   <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>kad</lastname>
      <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="593">
      <firstname>jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>singn</lastname>
      <nickname>jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

How do I design a java class to store `student` data. If sub-elements are stored as data members then how should I store the attribute `rollno`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use [JAXB](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) to map XML file into POJO objects.

Comment: Thanx this is a good clue to me and I think this will help me a lot to start with

Comment: on further reading is JAXB good for extremely large xml files. That is does it uses DOM or SAX internally @Nikolas Charalambidis

Comment: I assume a big file due the high numbers used (`rollno="593"`).

Answer (score 0):

First create a Student bean class as below:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nickName;
    private int marks;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can use [DOM](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parser.htm) parser or [SAX](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_sax_parser.htm) parser util populate the data.

Comment: I could understand less, you mean both attributes and elements should be data members in class @Bahramdun Adil

Comment: @user3282758 Yes you are right, but the ID is unique.

Comment: And what if there are more than one attributes to the element @Bahramdun Adil

Comment: You can create a field for that element in the Student class, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TransformerFactory class as shown:

```
try {
            
    Document document = null;
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    File f = new File(fileName + ".xml");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Remember that you have to add TransformerException to the method signature.